# Floating image to right in HTML lists causes alignment issues

Tags: css, css-float

For simplicity, I'm using inline styles so you can see what's going on.  I've used a red border for list elements and a black border for the images?  Why aren't the images aligned properly?  This has been driving me nuts.

See screenshot:

[image]

See code:

```
<ul>
<li style="border: 1px solid red">Result <span style="display: block; float: right; border: 1px solid #000"><img src="../../resources/images/delete.png" /></span></li>
<li style="border: 1px solid red">Result <span style="display: block; float: right; border: 1px solid #000"><img src="../../resources/images/delete.png" /></span></li>
<li style="border: 1px solid red">Result <span style="display: block; float: right; border: 1px solid #000"><img src="../../resources/images/delete.png" /></span></li>
</ul>
```

**JS Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/jMzub/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear the floats

```
<ul>
<li style="border: 1px solid red">Result 
<span style="display: block; float: right; border: 1px solid #000">
   <img src="../../resources/images/delete.png" />
</span>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</li>
<!--Same for other li-->
</ul>
```

But this is a dirty way, I would've used `background-image` and `background-position` for `<li>` element instead(Unless and until you'll be using image as a link or for some click purpose)

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Yeah, it was a background-image prior to me playing around with it.  I figured the li tag being a block-level element would've cleared the float by itself.  Guess not.

Comment: @GregH Block level elements doesn't clear the floats itself, you need to do it :) optionally you can use `oveflow: hidden;` on parent element but I always ignore doing so, if you don't need that cross to be clicked, just use `background-image` property and use `background-position` to set it right :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include height to li

```
li{height: 30px;}
```